# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xed'

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка

Такой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import time
import os
from threading import Thread

disks = []
tmp = []

class MyThread(Thread):


    def __init__(self, path):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        GetDirectory(self.path)


def GetDisk():
    for x in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X']:
        try:    
            path = x + ":\\"
            os.chdir(path)
            disks.append(path)
        except WindowsError:
            continue

def GetDirectory(path):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if((file.split('.')[-1]) in ['pdf','doc','mov','zip','docx','rtf','png','avi','mov','jpeg','jpg','rar','raw','docm','log','mp4','img','gif']):
                    sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                    tmp.append(sek)


def create_threads():
    for i in disks:
        path = i
        my_thread = MyThread(path)
        my_thread.start()
        my_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GetDisk()
    create_threads()
    handle = open('st.txt','a')
    for x in tmp:
        handle.write(x)
        handle.write('\n')
    handle.close()
```

Я получаю все доступные диски/флешки и прочее в системе, потом с помощью потоков рекурсивно собираю пути до файлов с определенным расширением, при попытки записи в файл эти пути я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
    handle.write(x)
  File "C:\python3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xed' in position 12
2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: А если так `open('st.txt','a')` -> `open('st.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке и стеку у вас подхватилась стандартная на системе кодировка - `cp1251` (`windows-1251`). Так происходит потому что в `open` не был указан `encoding`.

Попробуйте так:

```
with open('st.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for x in tmp:
        handle.write(x)
        handle.write('\n')
```

`st.txt` лучше перед этим удалить

Comment: В файле есть кракозябры M:\С„РѕС‚РѕРіСЂР°С„РёРё\С„РѕС‚Рѕ1\Photos\250611-1930.jpg. Как избавиться?

Comment: @Tayrus, когда указываете относительный путь, то место создания файлов определяется текущей рабочей папкой. Например, я открываю cmd и тот показывает путь `C://Users/gil9red` вот этот путь и будет текущей рабочей папкой. Если вы перешли в другую папку, то и путь поменяется на ее. Так что, или определитесь с текущей рабочей папкой, или указывайте полный путь к файлу, или, если нужно чтобы файл появился в папке скрипта, определяйте путь к текущему скрипту и сохраняйте его

Comment: Я понял уже как найти его, только как я и выше написал в файле присутствуют кракозябры.

Comment: `фотографии\фото1` да?

Comment: Я старый файл открыл, с вашими правками файл нормальный создался, извините.

Comment: @Tayrus, ааа :) просто, у вас файл был в кодировке cp1251, а записали туда utf-8

Comment: Зато работает))

Comment: @Tayrus, а куда оно денется -- конечно заработает :D